# Warning and fatal error

Tags: functions, comments, homepage, fatal-error, callbacks

I am getting this error when running my website :

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'sanitize_comment_cookies' not found or invalid function name in /homepages/9/d346623364/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_exists() (previously declared in /homepages/9/d346623364/htdocs/wp-includes/comment.php:27) in /homepages/9/d346623364/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/comment.php on line 43

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, **function 'sanitize_comment_cookies' not found or invalid function name** in /homepages/9/d346623364/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

This means you have a function named `sanitize_comment_cookies` hooked to an action or filter, either in your theme or a plugin, but that function is not available.

Look for the code: `add_action('some_action_name', 'sanitize_comment_cookies')` or `add_filter('some_filter_name', 'sanitize_comment_cookies')` and verify that the function name is correct.

---

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_exists()

Function `comment_exists` is defined in `wp-admin/includes/comment.php` and it should not be in the second location. From the message you can assume that you have modified  `wp-includes/comment.php` file. If that is the case, download the WordPress version you are using and replace the modified file with the original one.